# Matrix, index out of range

Tags: python

I've declared a matrix with the following code:

```
matrix = [[' ' for x in range(x1)] for x in range(y1)]
```

But when I try to find a random element and change it's value with the following code:

```
randomX = random.randint(0, x)
randomY = random.randint(0, y)
if matrix[randomX][randomY] == ' ':
    try:
        matrix[randomX][randomY] = 'G'
        scr.addstr(randomX, randomY, matrix[randomX][randomY])
        scr.refresh()
    except IndexError:
        return
```

I get an IndexError. I tried to just write some garbage code to exit the function if it runs in to an IndexError. It works once, then it still throws the error.

Note, x1 is the same as x in the function. Same goes with y1 and y.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: randint can take on the values 0 and x inclusively! so you might want to try randint(0,x-1), randint(0,y-1)

Comment: Yeah, tried that. Didn't change anything :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your indices are in wrong order. You should access them by

```
matrix[randomY][randomX]
```

or change the order in comprehension.

```
matrix = [[' ' for y in range(y1)] for x in range(x1)]
```

Also, as Garrett pointed out in comments, `randint()` is inclusive on both ends so you might want to use `randint(0,x-1)` and `randint(0,y-1)`.

Comment: That works. Still have to figure out why the indices should be accessed in that way, but I'll do some more work with it and hopefully I'll understand. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Your row width is dependent on **x1**; your column height is dependent on **y1**.  Look carefully at your nested comprehension.  Also note that you used **x** for both **for** variables.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes go out of range because radint picks a number including edges of scopes. x1 should be x1 = x + 1. But it is better not to have various variables where one is enough. Also, LafexIos right about indexing (first Y then X).

```
import random

x = 3
y = 4

matrix = [[' ' for ind_x in range(x)] for ind_y in range(y)]

for m in matrix:
    print m

print '---------------------'    

randomX = random.randint(0, x-1)
print 'random x: ', randomX
randomY = random.randint(0, y-1)
print 'random y: ', randomY

if matrix[randomY][randomX] == ' ':
    matrix[randomY][randomX] = 'G'

print '---------------------'
for m in matrix:
    print m
```

Output:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
---------------------
random x:  1
random y:  0
---------------------
[' ', 'G', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ']
```